# Visual Studio Graphics Debugger throwing Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx

I'm trying to start DirectX diagnostics with VS Graphics debugger, but I'm getting some kind of access violation in low level DLL like ntdll.dll. App launched with classic debugger works fine.

Does anyone have a clue what could it be?
[image: Error Message]

[image: Call Stack]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only clue is what that dialog says.  Did you choose `Break` and look at the call stack?

Comment: I attached call stack image

Comment: Anything in the output window? Did you build your device in debug mode? Where does that line of code originate from? You need to provide a lot more than just the generic exception box.

Comment: Yes, Device is built in debug mode.  This is my output window: [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/qvwMjwMQ). Could you please explain what do you mean by "Where does that line of code originate from?"